# Debugging undebuggable application for memory corruption

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, stack-overflow, memory-corruption

This is a bad situation: I have a large C++ application on Windows which is having a memory corruption.

Basically I dumped the content of a float variable and found the ASCII code of "hell" from a string elsewhere which was "hello world".

The big problem is: I can't debug it with a memory breakpoint since this is ONLY happening in release mode outside visual studio (release mode started by visual studio isn't triggering the bug, nor release with debug symbols).

Since the application is large and operates with lots of strings, I don't know how to debug it.

Do you have any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Libera te tutemet ex infernis.

Comment: +1 just for title:)  Can you twiddle with optimization levels to make a version with debug symbols that fails?  Also, link things in a different order, maybe?

Comment: Also, I have to ask, 'operates with lots of strings' - these strings, are they, by any chance, C-style strings with char*?

Comment: Unfortunately many C-style strings with char*, I would have preferred std::strings but I didn't write the code... very large, didn't count the lines but over 400.000+ I suppose

Comment: @CatPlusPlus http://youtu.be/mAfhwQxwD7I

Comment: If your code is portable, try GCC or Clang. With their warnings and support for AddressSanatizer and MemorySanatizer, they are very helpful.
Valgrind is very helpful but does not work on Windows. Maybe it's worth to try it together with Wine, see http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind
Maybe this dated question has some helpful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/413477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer. `printf`. Patience.

Comment: I strongly suspect char* strings :(